# Trying to remember name of old sci fi movie with robot and evil wizard

Tags: story-identification

All I remember is these kids find a robot out in their barn. Then they have to battle this wizard or sorcerer.

At some point, there's papers flying everywhere. The kids are trying to escape from the house, and this chubby kid opens a door and there's a giant cheeseburger or something.

I think the title was two words, something like "close encounters" or "coming something"

The movie was in color, and probably produced in the late 80s or early 90s.

Comment: Can you describe the kids (how many, what ages, what genders, what ethnicity)? What kind of wizard? How did they "battle" him (physically/with weapons/with magic)? How old was the film (black and white/ 1970s/1980s)? Can you describe the robot? What made this film memorable *to you*.

Comment: Honestly I barely remember anything. Movie was in color, prob late 80s early 90s, there was a group of kids. They find the robot out in a barn or something. Then there's this sorcerer or something causing trouble - one scene there's papers flying everywhere, the kids are trying to escape the house, one kid opens a door and there's a giant cheeseburger Haha. That's really all I remember

Comment: @user67126 It looks like you've created two user accounts. You can follow the instructions [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts together, so that you can edit and comment on your own question without needing other people to approve your edits or convert your 'answer' to a comment as I just did.

Comment: This sounds like the film "Making Contact" from 1985, about a young boy with super psychic powers. Also includes an evil ventriloquist dummy, as I recall.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the 1985 film "Making Contact" (AKA "Joey").

[Wikipedia Synopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joey_(1985_film)):

> The plot concerns a 9-year-old boy named Joey Collins (Joshua Morell) who loses his father, but makes contact with what he believes is his deceased parent via a small phone and is terrorized by a ventriloquist dummy named Fletcher who is possessed by a demon. The doll summons other demons and evil forces to threaten his friends, mother, enemies, city as only Joey must go into the spirit world to destroy this evil in a battle of good vs. evil. The boy develops the power of telekinesis, which soon gets out of hand.

I do not remember the robot part, but I do recall the kid finding the giant cheeseburger monster. The film's climactic scene takes a group of kids into a cellar, which morphs into a giant labyrinth.

[image]
<sup>Source: Wikipedia, linked above</sup>